# Pac-Man - Public Domain?

Tags: legal

I've googled this and haven't come up with anything. Can I create a Pac-Man game and not get in trouble with?

Like can I sell it, and be able to make money without having to pay someone else royalties?

Comment: NO. [SO says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201064/is-pac-man-still-protected-by-copyright)

Comment: 1. Maybe you should post this on a Stack Exchange site that has to do with law; it's more related to law than it is game development. 2. How does this have anything to do with c++?

Comment: I just needed to know. I was going to create it in C++ ;)

Comment: If a specific game is public domain or not is too localized in my opinion. Voting to close as too localized, and -1 for lack of basic research.

Comment: In the related questions we have the very popular http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/16455/982 Should that be closed for being too localized too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pac-Man

> In 2011, Namco sent a DMCA notice to the team that made the
>   programming language Scratch saying that a programmer had infringed
>   copyright by making a Pac-Man game using the language and uploading it
>   to Scratch's official website.[94]

Considering they sent a DMCA to someone who wasn't making money off of it I'm going with no.

Comment: Okay thanks. I guess I'll look into something else. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 9):

Pac-Man is still covered by copyright, and has not reverted to the public domain.

Exhaustively sourced proof:

1. [Copyright for works created during or after 1978 lasts a bare minimum of 70 years. (section 302.a)](http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap3.html)  (In the case of Pac-Man, 120 years is probably a more likely duration, as it presumably would have been a work for hire performed for Namco by its employees.  But we'll assume the minimum of 70 years for the rest of this proof)
2. [Pac-Man was created in 1980](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pac_man).
3. [At the time of writing, the year is 2013](http://whatyearisit.info/)
4. [2013 - 1978 = 35](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2013-1978&dataset=)
5. [35 < 70](http://lh4.ggpht.com/-mktQ6HQRlwM/TrKk4o77RmI/AAAAAAAACso/0t0VDI21fKI/Crocodiles-Eat-the-Biggest-Image7.jpg?imgmax=800)

Therefore, Pac-Man is still covered by Copyright.

[Quod erat demonstrandum](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quod_erat_demonstrandum)

Comment: Not to be too picky, but you might want to check your maths again.

Comment: It was, alas, a natural confusion, as I wrote this response whilst sitting comfortably within the decadent confines of my time machine, ten years hence.  ;)

Comment: Hehe, I thought it was something like that ;)

Comment: For lazy: pacman might become public domain in 2050.